# The comma operator example in ansi c 1999 TC3

Tags: c, c99, undefined-behavior

When I was trying to figure out, `!0`'s result is implementation defined expecting that it shall be unequal to zero I just read something what confused me.

(By the way may it be on some implementations `-1` or `1` or is it strict defined? If any one could me tell in comment would be nice)

But my real question is:

in

> 6.5.17 Comma operator 2

is said:

> If an attempt is made to modify the result of a comma operator or to
>   access it after the next sequence point, the behavior is undefined.

In exactly the next line there is an example how to parse a parameter into a function with use of comma operator.

```
f(a, (t=3, t+2), c);
```

But the example is in point of my knowledge so far undefined behavior, isn't it?
Since `t` gets assigned `3` and in the next sequence it gets increased by `2`.

But the standard doesn't mention that the example isn't valid.

Or is an assignment to be not understood as modification?

Comment: `But the standard doesn't mention that the example isn't valid.` That implies that the example is valid.

Comment: Yeah don't you say... but my question was WHY it is valid? as i understand the rule, it isn't

Comment: The == (equal to) and != (not equal to) operators are analogous to the relational
operators except for their lower precedence.93) Each of the operators yields 1 if the
specified relation is true and 0 if it is false. found it by my self .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `!0` evaluates to `1`
2. In `(t=3, t+2)`, there is a sequence point between the assignment and the access to `t`. The expression is defined, it evaluates to `5` and leaves the value `3` in `t`. It would be undefined if there was no sequence point between the two, for instance, `(t=3)+(t+2)`.

Comment: But why then `printf ("%d%d", t++, ++t)` is invalid? is the comma in a function call not to understand as sequencepoint?

Comment: @Zaibis Exactly. The commas in `printf ("%d%d", t++, ++t)` are not comma operators, and the paragraph in the standard that says that comma operators are sequence points does not apply to them.

Comment: ah so the parsed parameters to a function are a single sequence?

Comment: @Zaibis The arguments in a function call are **unsequenced**. This means that two of them are not allowed to modify and modify, or read and modify, the same memory location. The adjective “unsequenced” is not part of the C99 standard (that I remember) but it is used informally to describe two expressions that are not separated by a sequence point, e.g. in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what prompted you to ask the question.  The section of the standard that you've picked up the example from clearly says:

> As indicated by the syntax, the comma operator (as described in this subclause) cannot
>   appear in contexts where a comma is used to separate items in a list (such as arguments to functions or lists
>   of initializers). **On the other hand, it can be used within a parenthesized expression or
>   within the second expression of a conditional operator in such
>   contexts.** In the function call
>
> ```
>         f(a, (t=3, t+2), c)
> ```
>
> the function has
>   three arguments, the second of which has the value 5.

Emphasised the relevant portion to clarify your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

The comma operator introduces a sequence point, so that behavior should be well defined (first `t` is set to `3`, then `2` is added to `t` yielding the result `5` but keeping `3` in `t`).